# Using django-bootstrap-modal-forms on success, redirect to the initial page

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

Using `django-bootstrap-modal-forms`, I would like to redirect to the initial page, say /d/SimulationScenario/123/, after a successful POST request of modal form.
My guess is that this is done using `success_url`, but how can I pass an argument indicating the ID of the scenario, which is different each time, like here:

```
class EventCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    template_name = 'form_scenario_event_create.html'
    form_class = SimulationEventForm
    success_message = 'Success: Event was added to the scenario.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('detail_scenario', kwargs={'scenario_ID':123})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `success_url`, you can use the `get_success_url` method.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    scenario_id = ... # get scenario id
    return reverse_lazy('detail_scenario', kwargs={'scenario_ID': scenario_id})
```

Comment: Right, but still, self is an instance of EventCreateView. So how can I pass an argument for the scenario_id?

Comment: Try `self.object.scenario.id`.